# Underscore reduce returning memo as unidentified

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, reduce

I'm trying to learn the basics of Underscore.js and to be more precise, the reduce method.
As a basic exercise (following a video on Pluralsight) I'm taking a number of values from an array and trying to reduce them into a single value.

I'm certain it's something that'll make me hate myself once it's made clear, but at the moment I just can't get it to work despite my best efforts - my "memo" value is always returned as undefined.

The code:

```
log = function (input) { console.log(input); }

var data = {
    people: [
        { name: "Craig", state: "Alive", price: 100 },
        { name: "Bob", state: "Dead", price: 200 },
        { name: "Todd", state: "Dead", price: 300 },
        { name: "Cog", state: "Alive", price: 400 }
    ]
    };

   var total = _.reduce(data.people,
                        function( memo, value ) {
                            console.log('Memo price: ' + memo.price);
                            console.log('Value price: ' + value.price);
                            return { totalPrice: (memo.price + value.price) }; 
                        }, 0);

log("Total price: " + total);
```

The results:
value.price is returned as expected (100, 200, 300, 400)
memo.price is returned as "undefined"
Therefore total is returned as just an object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial memo value (the third argument to reduce), the first argument passed to your iterator function, and the value returned by the iterator, should all be compatible with each other. But:

- your initial value is just a plain number (`0`)
- you expect the first argument to the iterator function to be an object `{price: <a number>}`
- you return an object `{totalPrice: <a number>}`

To fix this, you just need to be consistent. For example, you could use plain numbers in all three cases:

```
_.reduce(data.people,
  function( memo, value ) {
      console.log('Memo price: ' + memo);
      console.log('Value price: ' + value.price);
      return memo + value.price; 
  }, 0);
```

Or you could use `{price: <a number>}` objects in all three cases:

```
_.reduce(data.people,
  function( memo, value ) {
      console.log('Memo price: ' + memo.price);
      console.log('Value price: ' + value.price);
      return {price: memo.price + value.price}; 
  }, {price: 0});
```

Comment: Ahh, that explains it all. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Thank you for explaining what was wrong, this sort of answer is actually useful to people.

Answer (score -1):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3QLR4/)

```
log = function (input) { console.log(input); }

var data = {
    people: [
        { name: "Craig", state: "Alive", price: 100 },
        { name: "Bob", state: "Dead", price: 200 },
        { name: "Todd", state: "Dead", price: 300 },
        { name: "Cog", state: "Alive", price: 400 }
    ]
    };

   var total = _.reduce(data.people,
                        function( memo, value ) {
                            console.log('Memo price: ' + memo.price);
                            console.log('Value price: ' + value.price);
                            return memo + value.price; 
                        }, 0);

log("Total price: " + total);
```

Comment: How is this blob of code a useful answer? And if you try to explain what's going on so that Applebough can learn something, then how would it be any different from the answer that was here an hour before yours?